# Backing up Whatsapp on Mac mini

Tags: iphone, backup, mac-mini, whatsapp.app, back-to-my-mac

I have been trying to backup WhatsApp with the app functionality but it seems impossible; it will throw a problem every time. I have tried backing it up using the iCloud "Back Up Now" inside *General → My Account → iCloud*, but I do not have enough space on iCloud; my WhatsApp messages sum up to more than 10GB.

I have searched for other ways to back up and I have found I can do this using my Mac mini and iTunes. The thing is, there's no more iTunes to download, but you can still make a backup of your phone when you access it through "Finder". The problem with this is I'm not sure the back up was successful, because it was quite fast and I don't know what type of information has been backed up.

So, my question is: if I back up using *Finder*, will all my WhatsApp data, including media of all sorts, be stored on my computer and will I be able to restore them if needed?

Note: I am trying a back up because I need to login with a different account on the iPhone and as far as I've read I can lose some data when I log back in.

Comment: idk specifically for WhatsApp, but make sure to set your iTunes/Finder back up to be Encrypted. Without encryption set, a lot of personal data is not saved.

Comment: On a slightly different note...you should be using [Signal](https://www.signal.org/) instead of WhatsApp if you value your privacy.  I've never had to back up anything and all my messages get "restored" when I move to a different computer.